# Postgres File System Sizes

Tags: linux, database, postgresql

Trying to setup Postgres Server and needs some advice.

What are the recommendations for these folders? what mount spaces should be required?

```
   /pgarchive 
   /pgbackup    
   /pgcluster 
   /pglog 
   /pgdata-system 
   /pgdata-temp 
   /pgdata-tblspc
```

Comment: I assume you got this list from [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Simple_Configuration_Recommendation). This is not any kind of official recommendation from Postgres, it's a user-created page on their wiki. Most of the approaches described are way, *way* overkill for 99.5% installations. If you're administering hundreds of servers, and moving tablespaces between physical disks is something you do on a daily basis, then there might be some useful advice in there. If you're setting up your first Postgres server, you can safely ignore it.

Comment: i wont be monitoring hundreds of servers but intend to set up of a few. So any recommendations would great

Comment: Hard to give general advice, depends very much on how you intend to use it. If you just want to get something off the ground, any random quick-start guide (and maybe some basic [tuning](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server)) is probably enough. If you need to become an expert DBA overnight, all I can recommend is to start reading [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html). The only thing I'd single out is to get a backup plan implemented before putting anything important in there ([`barman`](http://www.pgbarman.org/) might help).